# OCaml: When guard in "fun"

Tags: ocaml

If I'm reading it correctly, the OCaml documentation ([here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html), specifically) says that `fun` can have "when" guards, such as:

```
fun a b when a < b -> a + b;;
```

However, this throws a syntax error on the "when". What gives? Am I reading this wrong?

**More Info**

The relevant parts from the [documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html) are copied below in a BNF-like syntax:

```
expr ::= ...
       | fun multiple-matching
       | ...

multiple-matching ::= { pattern }+ [when expr] -> expr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a bug of the documentation. `fun` cannot take a guard.

Note: the fix is already pull-requested: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-manual/pull/2

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Thanks!